# Cannot find innerHTML of null, css3 transition flip

Tags: javascript, html, css

I keep getting errors for this particular piece of code. Specifically, it's an uncaught typeerror, and it says that an id is null, even though it isn't.

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
             <title>Flip the card over </title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cardFlipper.css">
             <script>
            var front = new Array("ante","anti","bi","circum","com","con","de","dis","equi","extra","inter","intra")
            var back = new Array("before","against","bi","around","together","together","down","away","equal","beyond","between","within")
            var placeholder = eval(0);
            var cardFront = document.getElementById("cFront").innerHTML
            var cardBack = document.getElementById("cBack").innerHTML
            function rightCard()
            {
            placeholder += 1
            cardFront = front[placeholder]
            cardBack = back[placeholder]
            }
            function leftCard()
            {
            placeholder -= 1
            cardFront = front[placeholder]
            cardBack = back[placeholder]
            }
            function flipCard(theCard)
            {
                if(theCard.className == 'front')
                        theCard.className='flipped';
                else
                        theCard.className='front';
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=deck class="container">
                <div id="card" onClick="flipCard(this)">
                        <figure class="front" id="cFront">ante</figure>
                        <figure class="back" id="cBack">before</figure>
                </div>
        </div>
        <input type=button id=left value="<-----" onclick="leftCard()">
        <p class=tab></p>
        <input type=button id=right value="----->" onclick="rightCard()">


    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is the CSS. I am trying to change the text in the figure to something that works.

```
    .tab { margin-left: 40px; 
    }
    .container{ 
        width: 200px;
        height: 260px;
        position: relative;
        perspective: 800px;
        -webkit-perspective: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto 40px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
    #card {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: transform 1s;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
}
#card figure {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        color: white;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 260px;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#card .front{
        background: red;
}
#card .back {
        background: blue;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg );
}

#card.flipped {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg );
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you run your javascript the DOM isn't loaded and the elements

```
 var cardFront = document.getElementById("cFront").innerHTML
 var cardBack = document.getElementById("cBack").innerHTML
```

actually are not set and therefor not found.

Wrap your code in

```
window.onload = function() {

        var front = new Array("ante","anti","bi","circum","com","con","de","dis","equi","extra","inter","intra")
        var back = new Array("before","against","bi","around","together","together","down","away","equal","beyond","between","within")
        var placeholder = eval(0);
        var cardFront = document.getElementById("cFront").innerHTML
        var cardBack = document.getElementById("cBack").innerHTML
        function rightCard()
        {
        placeholder += 1
        cardFront = front[placeholder]
        cardBack = back[placeholder]
        }
        function leftCard()
        {
        placeholder -= 1
        cardFront = front[placeholder]
        cardBack = back[placeholder]
        }
        function flipCard(theCard)
        {
            if(theCard.className == 'front')
                    theCard.className='flipped';
            else
                    theCard.className='front';
        }

}
```

then it will work.

To improve the loading speed of your page, I would recommend to put your javascript code at the end of your file, right before the closing `</body>` tag.

I don't see a reason why you use **eval()**. The eval function is slow. If you're using it unecessarily, you're slowing down your program for no reason. One cause of this is the fact that the engine has to parse the argument as a complete new program

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm quite the amateur. I decided to try and learn HTML and CSS and am just trying something. Thanks.